# RX misunderstood behavior

Tags: system.reactive

I have the below repro code which demonstrate a problem in a more complex flow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = Observable.Range(1, 10).Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed"));
        var x = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    o.OnNext(i);
                }

                o.OnCompleted();

                return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed"));
            });

        var src = x.Publish().RefCount();

        var a = src.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Pair:" + i));
        var b = src.Where(i => i % 2 != 0).Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Even:" + i));

        var c = Observable.Merge(a, b);

        using (c.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("final " + i), () => Console.WriteLine("Complete")))
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

running this snippet with r as src (`var src = r.Publish().RefCount()`) will produce all the numbers from 1 till 10,
switching the src to x(like in example) will produce only the pairs, actually the first observable to subscribe unless i change Publish() to Replay().

Why? What is the difference between r and x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I do not have the patience to sort through the [Rx.NET](http://rx.codeplex.com) source code to find exactly what implementation detail causes this exact behavior, I can provide the following insight:

The difference in behavior your are seeing is caused by a race condition. The racers in this case are the subscriptions of `a` and `b` which happen as a result of your subscription to the observable returned by `Observable.Merge`. You subscribe to `c`, which in turn subscribes to `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` are defined in terms of a `Publish` and `RefCount` of either `x` or `r`, depending on which case you choose.

## Here's what's happening.

### src = r

In this case, you are using a custom Observable. When subscribed to, your custom observible *immediately* and *synchronously* begins to `onNext` the numbers 1 though 10, and then calls `onCompleted`. Interestingly enough, this subscription is caused by your  `Publish().RefCount()` Observable when it is subscribe to ***the first time***. It is subscribed to the first time by `a`, because `a` is the first parameter to `Merge`. So, before `Merge` has even subscribed to `b`, your subscription has already completed. `Merge` subscribes to `b`, which is the `RefCount` observable. That observable is already completed, so `Merge` looks for the next Observable to merge. Since there are no more Observables to merge, and because all of the existing Observables have completed, the merged observable completes.

The values onNext'd through your custom observable have traveled through the "pairs" observable, but not the "evens" observable. Therefore, you end up with the following:

```
// "pairs" (has this been named incorrectly?)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

### src = x

In this case, you are using the built-in `Range` method to create an Observable. When subscribed to, this Range Observable ***does something that eventually ends up yielding the numbers 1 though 10***. Interesting. We haven't a clue what's happening in that method, or *when* it's happening. We can, however, make some observations about it. If we look at what happens when `src = r` (above), we can see that only the first subscription takes effect because the observable is yielding ***immediately and synchronously***. Therefore, we can determine that the Range Observable must not be yielding in the same manner, but instead allows the application's control flow to execute the subscription to `b` *before* any values are yielded. The difference between your custom Observable and this Range Observable, is probably that the Range Observable is *scheduling* the yields to happen on the `CurrentThread` Scheduler.

## How to avoid this kind of race condition:

```
var src = a.Publish(); // not ref count

var a = src.where(...);
var b = src.where(...);

var c = Observable.Merge(a, b);

var subscription = c.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("final " + i), () => Console.WriteLine("Complete"))

// don't dispose of the subscription. The observable creates an auto-disposing subscription which will call dispose once `OnCompleted` or `OnError` is called.

src.Connect(); // connect to the underlying observable, *after* merge has subscribed to both a and b.
```

Notice that the solution to fixing the subscription to this composition of Observables was not to change how the source observable works, but instead to make sure your subscription logic isn't allowing any race conditions to exist. This is important, because trying to fix this problem in the Observable is simply changing behavior, not fixing the race. Had we changed the source and switched it out later, the subscription logic would still be buggy.

Comment: Since Merge doesn't subscribe to the observable async, would you consider it a good practice when using Observable.Create to schedule the action on a different thread then current?

Comment: I consider it good practice to consider what exactly you intend your source observable to do. In this case, you implemented it exactly as I would have, unless I was going to onNext a very high number of events. In that case, I would have the recursive scheduling method on the CurrentThread Scheduler to either yield individual events, or small batches of events, non-blocking over a short period of time. Basically just to allow other code to have control flow.

Comment: Observables and Observers both need to be considered. One is the producer, the other the consumer. Neither's behavior should be dictated by the other. One should not make assumption about when, where, or how the other is working. That said, they should play nice together. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the schedulers. This change causes the two to behave identically:

```
var x = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                o.OnNext(i);
            }

            o.OnCompleted();
        });

        return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed"));
    });
```

Whereas using `Scheduler.Immediate` gives the same behavior as yours.